# [Error writting extended attribute ]can't write extended attribute when outside of /tmp directory

Tags: java, nio

I am trying to write an `UserDefinedFileAttribute` to a file.

```
UserDefinedFileAttributeView view = Files.getFileAttributeView(myFile,UserDefinedFileAttributeView.class);

view.write("myattibute",Charset.defaultCharset().encode("1234");
```

i made sure the file permissions are correct it seems. however when this piece of code runs o UNIX i get the Error

> Error writing extended attribute :Operation Not supported

however if i update the file in the /tmp directory it works?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you are looking for but in Windows this works (for me and perhaps for you too):

```
public static boolean writeCustomMETAfile(String filepath,String name, String value) {
    boolean succes = false;
    try {
        Path file = Paths.get(filepath);
        UserDefinedFileAttributeView userView = Files.getFileAttributeView(file, UserDefinedFileAttributeView.class);
        //userView.write(name, Charset.defaultCharset().encode(value));

         final byte[] bytes = value.getBytes("UTF-8");
         final ByteBuffer writeBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(bytes.length);
         writeBuffer.put(bytes);
         writeBuffer.flip();

        userView.write(name, writeBuffer);
        succes = true;

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return succes;
}
```

With a JUnit test:

```
@Test
public void B_getFileInfo(){
    String filepath = "....your.File";
    METAdao.writeCustomMETAfile(filepath,"test","true");
    String[] attribList = METAdao.readCustomMETAfile(filepath);
    String[] expected1 = {"test"};
    assertArrayEquals(expected1, attribList);
    String test = METAdao.readCustomMETAfile(filepath,"test");
    assertEquals("true", test);
    METAdao.deleteCustomMETAfile(filepath,"test");
    String[] recheck = METAdao.readCustomMETAfile(filepath);
    String[] expected2 = {};
    assertArrayEquals(expected2, recheck);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're probably trying to write extended attributes to a filesystem which does not support it. In this situation, Java erroneously returns non-`null` for the `UserDefinedFileAttributeView` even though, leading client code to think it will work.